# I got an error when installing and using the discord JS termux bot

Tags: javascript, android, discord.js, termux

[Link github bot](https://github.com/Adivise/NanoSpace/tree/master)
`

/sdcard/NanoSpace $ npm install

npm WARN deprecated @discordjs/collection@0.3.2: no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated @discordjs/rest@0.2.0-canary.0: no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated locale-parser@1.1.3: Use @hammerhq/localization

npm WARN deprecated discord-api-types@0.25.2: No longer supported. Install the latest release!

[##################] / reify:figlet: timing reifyNode:node_modu

> node@17.9.1 preinstall

> node installArchSpecificPackage

npm ERR! code E404#] \ reify:figlet: timing reifyNode:node_modu

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-android-arm - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  'node-android-arm@17.9.1' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2024-02-29T14_11_03_300Z-debug-0.log

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147timing reifyNode:node_modu

throw err;

^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-android-arm/package.json'

Require stack:

- /storage/emulated/0/NanoSpace/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js

  at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)

  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:187:19)

  at ChildProcess. (/storage/emulated/0/NanoSpace/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:19:27)

  at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)

  at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)

  at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5) {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: [

  '/storage/emulated/0/NanoSpace/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'

  ]

}

Node.js v20.11.1

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path /storage/emulated/0/NanoSpace/node_modules/node

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command sh -c node installArchSpecificPackage

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2024-02-29T14_10_32_011Z-debug-0.log

/sdcard/NanoSpace $`

Help me I hope everyone can help me fix the above error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.